# trim() для файлов , удаление пустых строк

Tags: php, файлы

Всем привет.

Есть скрипт который записывает информацию в файл, и есть другой (скрипт) который удаляет ее при надобности.

Нужна функция для удаление пробелов и переносов строк прямо из файла, пробовал `trim()`, но это вроде для строки, а не для самого файла.

Посоветуете что?

Может забыл про какую то функцию.
Пример

```
if(file_put_contents($admfile, PHP_EOL . $admexphrase, FILE_APPEND)) {
    echo "succesadm";
}
```

//запись в файл с переносом строки

// что получилось

```
1- <p><a href="admintour110.php">tour23.php</a></p>
2- <p><a href="admintour115.php">tour24.php</a></p>
3- <p><a href="admintour120.php">tour25.php</a></p>
```

//вот что получается при удалении этой строки

```
1- <p><a href="admintour110.php">tour23.php</a></p>
2- <p><a href="admintour115.php">tour24.php</a></p>
3-
```

//при повторной записи

```
1- <p><a href="admintour110.php">tour23.php</a></p>
2- <p><a href="admintour115.php">tour24.php</a></p>
3 -
4- <p><a href="admintour120.php">tour25.php</a></p>
```

//если удалить последнюю строку еще раз и перезаписать выйдет это

//при повторной записи

```
1- <p><a href="admintour110.php">tour23.php</a></p>
2- <p><a href="admintour115.php">tour24.php</a></p>
3-
4- 
5- <p><a href="admintour120.php">tour25.php</a></p>
```

//удаляю с помощью str_replace

```
$admstring = '<p><a href="admintour120.php">tour25.php</a></p>';
$admcontold = array("$admstring");
$admcontnew = array("");
$admphrase  = str_replace($admcontold, $admcontnew, $admcont);
if(file_put_contents($admlist, $admphrase)) {
    echo "succes page\n";
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: добавил выше пример

Comment: `$admstring = '<p><a href="admintour120.php">tour25.php</a></p> . PHP_EOL';`

Comment: щас попробую, напишу ответ

Comment: к сожалению не сработало ..

Comment: 1,2,3, - часть строки?

Comment: `preg_replace('/^.*(<p><a href="admintour120.php">tour25.php</a></p>).*$/m', '', $fileContent);`

Comment: нет , это номер строки в редакторе , написал чтобы было понятнее

Comment: приведенный вами код , на конкретную строку? 
мне желательно на все строки ) потому что я не вручную пишу , а скрипт сам создает

Comment: щас попробую регулярку

Comment: Это пример генерирует то что в крулых скобках динамически

Comment: да понял , а вместо чего мне его ставить? вместо preg_replace ? или вместо той строки которую нужно заменить

Comment: <p>....</p>.  Оффтоп зачем? Не проще хранить в базе, например redis и при изменении генерировать файл с 0. Так и разметку менять легче

Comment: регулярка вообще сносит все на своем пути ) стирает весь текст вместе с пробелами , ну так получилось что надо в фс все организовать

Comment: придумал вариант , убрать PHP_EOL , из этого скрипта

file_put_contents($admfile, PHP_EOL . $admexphrase, FILE_APPEND))

но теперь нужно написать вместо него \n , чтобы он работал в самом файле , и когда будет удалять сделать следующее
$admstring = '\n<p><a href="admintour120.php">tour25.php</a></p>';
и заменять ее на пустую строку, только \n вроде в текстовый файл будет писаться как текст , разве нет?

Comment: `PHP_EOL` системно независимый конец строки(`"\n"`)

Comment: да , но вот , его почемуто не получается заменить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел хороший код , который вполне устраивает

Указываем путь к файлу , в котором хотим наладить порядок , убрать лишние пробелы и переводы строки и все работает.
Код Ниже :

```
$c = 'content/text.php'; //читаем отсюда 
$cont = file_get_contents($c);
$cont = trim(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/m","\r\n", $cont));


file_put_contents('content/test.php', $cont); //записываем сюда
```

//можно читать и записывать в один и тотже файл , я так и сделал.
спасибо всем кто пытался помочь выше, ставлю плюсы.

Answer (score 2):

Есть еше и такой вариант без замены строк:

**test.txt**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

// read
$data = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

//  remove

$idx = array_search('line 1', $data);

if ($idx !== false) {
    unset($data[$idx]);
}

// add
$data[] = 'brand new line';


// write

file_put_contents(
    'test.txt',
    join(PHP_EOL, $data)
);
```

Comment: спасибо , попробую и посмотрю как это работает

Comment: как дополнение к ответу попробуй sqlite... И нечего кастыли разводить @S1lllver

Comment: @Naumov Я уже советовал автору вопроса работать с базой. Говорит не подходит.

Comment: ну так sqlite в файл пишет. Я видел поэтому вам плюс, а сообщение автору было адресованно.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы писали в файл, вы пишете с `PHP_EOL`, а при удалении уже без него.
Достаточно в скрипт удаления добавить `PHP_EOL`, и код удаления будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

`$admcontold = PHP_EOL . $admstring;`

Думаю, ваш вариант будет дорого обходится серверу. Если файл будет большой, он может не вместиться в выделенный память, да и регулярные выражения будут отнимать много времени.